# Colors are not rotating in Highcharts Bubble chart

Tags: highcharts

I would like the bubble's color have different colors according to their value from 2 colors range (lightest is low value and darkest is higher value).
I used the colors array like this:

```
colors: ['#69ADC7', '#4F4899']
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL0p9cu6/4/) here

But still I get only 1 color for al bubbles.
Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using object in data so you must define the color for each object :

```
...
{
  x: 74.2,
  y: 68.5,
  z: 141.5,
  name: 'FR',
  country: 'France',
  color:'#4F4899'
}
...
```

**Edit**

Add this code :

```
plotOptions: {
  series:{
    colorByPoint:true
  }
},
```

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tL0p9cu6/6/) - [Api link](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bubble.data)

Comment: what I can use for data so the colours would be auto assigned?

Comment: thank you. It looks great. Is it possible to use the 2 colors as range boundaries? I mean that the first color is the start point and the second color is the end point, and then all the colors are auto assigned by the highest data value?

Comment: (like in heatmaps)

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34092997/highcharts-bar-chart-with-bar-colored-based-on-value) , not sure anyway how to use it in this case.